# How to restart .py program when it stop itself from error

Tags: python

I have basically a bot build by python and currently run by cmd on my PC. Because it use a web API so when there is a connection problem (I think), it return a 0 value, which I divided to, and it thow a Divided by zero error and stop.
I want to ask if I can automatically rerun the program after it stop itself in someway or if I put my bot up to the cloud, could it be restart itself if problems like this occur?

Comment: Simplest solution is to wrap the bot startup with a try block wrapped in a while loop

Answer (score 1):

Put your program's code in a function like so:

```
def main():
    try:
        #do stuff here
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        main()
```

The function restarts itself when the code raises `ZeroDivisionError`.